# Sort array PHP (Order array php)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my array () ...not much English'm using google translator.
I'm printing this array with print_r (). but what I deceo is sort of form this down

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 606125999550609
            [1] => Patricia
            [2] => Michelle
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 724417787635260
            [1] => Nasshy
            [2] => Green
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1121064174618668
            [1] => Luisanna
            [2] => Rodriguez
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1057585894278115
            [1] => Libane
            [2] => Heredia
        )

)
```

Basically what I need is to sort this array as follows......
So I do not know how to sort follows in PHP...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 606125999550609
    [1] => 724417787635260
    [2] => 1121064174618668
    [3] => 1057585894278115

    [4] => Patricia
    [5] => Nasshy
    [6] => Luisanna
    [7] => Libane

    [8] => Michelle
    [9] => Green
    [10] => Rodriguez
    [11] => Heredia
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't so much "sorting", its' more of a manipulation/restructure. Using a loop to regenerate your array would be the option, but if you can modify the data from where it comes from, then that's always recommended.

```
$new = array();
array_map(function($obj) use(&$new) {
    foreach($obj as $i => $elem) {
        $new[$i][] = $elem;
    }
}, $array);
```

In the example above, we're using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) to apply our `function() {...` that runs the loop of each element, applying it to our `$new` array.

All you need to do is pass your `$array` in as you see above.

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#xFFH0d3wj)

Comment: Thanks for the help